# How do I create an Accessor for a POINT data column in a Laravel 4 model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geospatial, point

I've got a user_sessions table that has a column named "geo_location", it's a POINT column that stores the latitude and longitude values for a user's current location, or NULL if it's not available.

When I create a Model in Laravel that binds to that table it only works when the geo_location field is hidden completely. Otherwise it throws a JSON error because it's not properly querying for the separate X and Y values in the geo_location column.

Is there a way that I can create an Accessor in my Laravel Model that can manipulate the data before it gets displayed so that I can include it in my results?

Do I need to modify my UserSessions controller and add a get() function to just use raw SQL instead?

Comment: You mean other than the native accessor method available in eloquent? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: I mentioned the Accessor in my question's text body, so yes, I have tried it. I've looked thoroughly through their documentation and they do not touch upon applying raw SQL functions (in this case, X(column_name), and Y(column_name)) to geospatial column types.

At this point my only solution has been to just access the data from a different model using raw SQL, i.e. DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT X(geo_location)...")). I would prefer to have an entire Model and Controller setup to handle this though using Accessors somehow...

Comment: What happens when you use `$this->attributes['geo_location']` in the accessor?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PostGreSQL + PostGIS, this is how I did it for L4.1

location is of type geometry(POINT), created using a raw sql query in the migration table

Table:

```
 DB::statement("ALTER TABLE places ADD COLUMN location GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)");
```

Model:

```
 class Place extends Eloquent{
     //mass assignment of fillable field
     #fillable
     protected $fillable = array('name', 'attribute', 'location');
     // if you want to include your POINT data as a JSON attribute
     #append
     protected $append = array('location');
     // the DB:raw statement is particular to PostGreSQL + PostGIS, a native function of PostGIS
     // basically, find the id of the referred place
     // and run the PostGIS function that turns the geometry type to wkt text.
     #accessor
     public function getLocationAttribute(){
         $id =  $this->attributes['id'];
         $wkt = DB::table('places')->find( $id, array(DB::raw('ST_AsText(location) AS location')));
         $location = $wkt->location;
         return $location;
     }

 }
```

a sample output using REST looks like this:

{domain}/place/{1}

```
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Yellowstone",
  created_at: "2014-05-19 08:19:51",
  updated_at: "2014-05-19 08:19:51",
  location: "POINT(121.1 14.4)"
 }
```

Note:

using a default accessor

```
  $this->attributes['location']
```

returns a Hexadecimal Object, rather than a string. so i opted to use a raw query with a PostGIS function.

```
 {
   id: 1,
   name: "Yellowstone",
   created_at: "2014-05-19 08:19:51",
   updated_at: "2014-05-19 08:19:51",
   location: "0101000020E61000006666666666465E40CDCCCCCCCCCC2C40"
 }
```

From the WKT, i hope you can easily return the longitude / latitude using native php scripts. :-)

I hope this gives you an idea on how to create the accessor.

Comment: How should I write a `setLocationAttribute()` method?

Comment: i haven't tried that, though, but i suspect it's another 'DB::raw' statemant. I will be looking into that as soon as I get my hands back on Laravel :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using the following methods. However these seem to be not that efficient.

`DB::table('activities')->find( $id, array(DB::raw('AsText(geolocation) as geolocation')));`
`$this->attributes['geolocation'] = DB::raw("GeomFromText('POINT(".$values[0]." ".$values[1].")')");`

Comment: i have been watching a related thread before , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288633/what-is-the-mysql-datatype-set-equivalent-in-laravel-schema/25359038#25359038) may help. The link extends Lavarel's default classes and use the extended class in grammar and blueprint classes. Haven't tried, though. :-)

Comment: When you have like 1000 objects (Places) in memory and you iterate through them, the Accessor method will do 1000 queries to the database. Sometimes this is unacceptable. Did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: @Jorrit, yes that is unacceptable.

actually i found a better way using model events, which eliminates the need for that query. i will edit my answer soon.

Answer (score -1):

I used a global scope in the model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
...
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::addGlobalScope('geometry', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->select()->selectRaw("(ST_AsText(geo_location)) as geo_location");
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes