# What is the MySQL datatype SET equivalent in Laravel Schema?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, schema

[Laravel Schema](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) has a command for ENUM equivalent to the table. What is the SET equivalent to the table?

Comment: Version 5.8 onwards, supports set columns as well

$table->set('flavors', ['strawberry', 'vanilla']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel 5.8 and onwards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) support **SET** datatype in migration. For latest versions, you would simply need to use [`set()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1f7e0e4e95779b580357a7174fb4286dc3fb8ed1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L947) function:

```
// SET equivalent column named flavors
// Allowed values: strawberry , vanilla
$table->set('flavors', ['strawberry', 'vanilla']);
```

Check more details at latest documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations
- https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_set

Answer (score 18):

**Step 1.** Extend default classes(add this code to your migration file after `use` sections):

```
class ExtendedBlueprint extends Blueprint {

    /**
     * Create a new set column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  array   $allowed
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function set($column, array $allowed)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('set', $column, compact('allowed'));
    }

}


class ExtendedMySqlGrammar extends Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar {

    /**
     * Create the column definition for an set type.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
     * @return string
     */
    protected function typeSet(\Illuminate\Support\Fluent $column)
    {
        return "set('".implode("', '", $column->allowed)."')";
    }

}
```

**Step 2.** Then, we need to change default grammar and blueprint classes to our custom:

```
// set new grammar class
DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new ExtendedMySqlGrammar());

// get custom schema object
$schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

// bind new blueprint class
$schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
    return new ExtendedBlueprint($table, $callback);
});

// then create tables 
$schema->create('table name', function(ExtendedBlueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('sentence');
    $table->string('author')->nullable();
    $table->string('source')->nullable();
    $table->set('difficulty', range(1, 10)); // use our new mysql type 
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
});
```

This method will also work after `composer update`, because we did not edited any framework code.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I do this. `Argument 1 passed to CreateTableName::{closure}() must be an instance of ExtendedBlueprint, instance of Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint given` Any thoughts? I did change Blueprint to ExtendedBlueprint in my create callback.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using `Schema::create( ... )` instead of $schema->create( ... )

Answer (score 11):

As of now Laravel Schema Builder does not support SET datatype for columns. So, here is an alternative solution until someone add those code to Laravel.

**Step 1:** Create the table, use ENUM instead of SET.

```
Schema::create('schools', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->char('id_number', 6);
    $table->string('school_name');
    $table->enum('level', array('Preschool', 'Kindergarten', 'Primary', 'Secondary'))->index(); // *** fix this
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('location');
    $table->smallInteger('city')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->smallInteger('country')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->smallInteger('head_teacher')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->smallInteger('director')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->smallInteger('created_by')->unsigned();
    $table->smallInteger('modified_by')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Step 2:** Now change ENUM to SET.

```
$table_prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . $table_prefix . "schools` CHANGE `level` `level` SET('Preschool','Kindergarten','Primary','Secondary');");
```

If you have a better solution, then please let me know.

Comment: Why not just add the table afterwards (using a `DB::statement` call)?  Why do you add it, then alter it?

Comment: @ajon Good question. I have done like that to keep the usage of `DB::statement` to minimal.

Answer (score 4):

Roman Nazarkin's method works almost perfectly however there is a small issue with table prefixes (which this method does not account for) it is simple however to make this suggestion work with table prefixes:

```
$grammar = DB::connection()->withTablePrefix(new ExtendedMySqlGrammar());
// set new grammar class
DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar($grammar);

// get custom schema object
$schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

// bind new blueprint class
$schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
    return new ExtendedBlueprint($table, $callback);
});

// then create tables 
$schema->create('table name', function(ExtendedBlueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('sentence');
    $table->string('author')->nullable();
    $table->string('source')->nullable();
    $table->set('difficulty', range(1, 10)); // use our new mysql type 
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My simple once-off solution when you need to create a custom column without creating additional files to describe extended grammar. Here I add my custom type `rsvp_statuses` into `PostgresGrammar`:

```
    public function up()
    {
        DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new class extends PostgresGrammar {
            protected function typeRsvp_statuses(\Illuminate\Support\Fluent $column)
            {
                return 'rsvp_statuses';
            }
        });

        Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            //...
            $table->addColumn('rsvp_statuses', 'status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Extending laravel database schema methods is not too hard. Like Roman wrote, instead of extending, you can as well update your

#### vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammers/MysqlGrammer.php

```js
/**
 * Create the column definition for an set type.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
 * @return string
*/
protected function typeSet(Fluent $column){
    return "set('".implode("', '", $column->allowed)."')";
}
```

#### vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php

```js
/**
     * Create a new set column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  array   $allowed
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
    */
    public function set($column, array $allowed){
        return $this->addColumn('set', $column, compact('allowed'));
    }
```

After this, terminate your server by pressing Ctrl + C. Then type php artisan serve to start the laravel.