# What is the correct way to extend MySqlGrammar and bind to IOC in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, ioc-container

I wanted to extend the MySqlGrammer to provide support for the MySql colum type 'set' while using the database in my workbench package.

Having searched around for other peoples attempts to do this I found some examples that appeared to do what i wanted:

- http://blog.stidges.com/post/extending-the-connection-class-in-laravel
- http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=34937
- [What is the MySQL datatype SET equivalent in Laravel Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288633/what-is-the-mysql-datatype-set-equivalent-in-laravel-schema)

I tried copying the first two methods above, but both methods produce errors any time I try to migrate. The first method gives:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = services_migrations and table_name = ?)
```

The second method gives:

```
[ErrorException]
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, array given, ...
```

The third method seemed at first glance to work just fine, it created the right columns in my database table, however when using table prefixes in my config this method failed to use the table prefixes and I had to manually prefix my table names to get it to work.

I am pretty sure that the overridden classes in the above examples are the right way to do it, the issues seems to be how to properly bind and override/extend laravel to inform it of the class changes. Currently I am attempting to do this in my service providers register() method, which seems to me to be the most obvious place to put this code.

For reference the code I am using looks like this:

file: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php

```
<?php 
namespace Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema\Grammars;

class MySqlGrammar extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar
{
    protected function typeSet(\Illuminate\Support\Fluent $column)
    {
        return "set('".implode("', '", $column->allowed)."')";
    }
}
```

file: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php

```
<?php namespace Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema;

class Blueprint extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint
{
    public function set($column, array $allowed)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('set', $column, compact('allowed'));
    }
}
```

file: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Database/Schema/Builder.php

```
<?php 
namespace Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema;

class Builder extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder
{
    protected function createBlueprint($table, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        return new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema\Blueprint($table, $callback);
    }
}
```

file: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Database/MySqlConnection.php

```
<?php namespace Iccle\Quake3\Database;

class MySqlConnection extends \Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection
{
    protected function getDefaultSchemaGrammar()
    {
        return $this->withTablePrefix(new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar);
    }

    public function getSchemaBuilder()
    {
        if (is_null($this->schemaGrammar)) { $this->useDefaultSchemaGrammar(); }

        return new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema\Builder($this);
    }
}
```

File: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Quake3ServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Iccle\Quake3;

use \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class Quake3ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('iccle/quake3');

        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../routes.php');
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../filters.php');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        //Method 1, causes exceptions during migrations
        // $this->app->singleton('db.connection.mysql', function($app, $parameters)
        // {
        //  list($connection, $database, $prefix, $config) = $parameters;
        //  return new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\MySqlConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
        // });

        //Method 2, doomed to failure because it does not pass enough parameters to \Illuminate\Database\Connection::__construct
        //$this->app->resolving('db', function($db) {
        //  $db->extend('mysql', function($config) {
        //      return new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\MySqlConnection($config);
        //  });
        //});
    }


    public function provides()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

My question in short is what is the recommended/correct way to inform laravel of my overridden database classes in my service provider, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my package written a while ago
https://github.com/rafis/schema-extended

Answer (score 1):

I fell on the same error so other people might find this useful. Laravel has a special Builder for Mysql that is not the default builder. So in your code you need to specify this special Builder :

file: workbench/iccle/quake3/src/Iccle/Quake3/Database/Schema/Builder.php

```
<?php 
namespace Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema;

class Builder extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder
{
    protected function createBlueprint($table, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        return new \Iccle\Quake3\Database\Schema\Blueprint($table, $callback);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick !

Xavier