# Laravel Schema Builder timestamp *with* timezone

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I am trying to add a `timestamp with time zone` column to my PostgreSQL database table using the Laravel Schema Builder.

The Schema Builder provides the function `$table->timestamps()` which generates the columns `created_at` and `updated_at` as `timestamp without time zone`. How can I add the timestamps **with** a time zone? Is there any further documentation besides the [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema)?

Comment: The timezone is decided by your `app.timezone` config and then used when receiving the time with PHP (etc. Carbon).

Comment: So it is always assumed that the timestamp stores the time in the configured timezone? What about using the same database with differend apps in differend timezones? The timezone has to be stored in the database somehow and I think this is what `timestamp with timezone` is for in Postgres.

Comment: @Mouagip I think you (and Postgres) are right about this, but many DB vendors don't implement `timestamp with timezone`. Laravel may choose this way, because simple `timestamp`s could be vendor independent. This [discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3393) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288633/what-is-the-mysql-datatype-set-equivalent-in-laravel-schema/25359038#25359038) on SO might interest you.

Comment: @pozs Pretty verbose for adding a simple timezone. But I understand the difficulties with maintaining support for different databases etc. so this seems to be the only solution yet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible to use the `timestampsTz` function when using Postgres as of this commit - https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1afb3d164dedc305d7ecead87262bef6d9218885