# How to insert values for SET Column type for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, set

I am trying to use the Laravel Set Column type. I have been able to create a table with it, but I couldn't find any information regarding how to actually insert data into it. My schema format

```
    Schema::create('bundles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('BID');
        $table->set('bundle', ['A', 'B', 'C']);
    });
```

My code to try to insert

```
$insert = DB::table('bundles')->insert(['bundle'=>['A', 'B']]);
```

but it throws the error

> ```
>    ErrorException 
>
>   ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
>
>   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2817
>     2813▕         // in the same order for the record. We need to make sure this is the case
>     2814▕         // so there are not any errors or problems when inserting these records.
>     2815▕         else {
>     2816▕             foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
>   ➜ 2817▕                 ksort($value);
>     2818▕ 
>     2819▕                 $values[$key] = $value;
>     2820▕             }
>     2821▕         }
>
>       +1 vendor frames 
>   2   database/migrations/2020_12_24_072449_bundles.php:31
>       Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()
>
>       +32 vendor frames 
>   35  artisan:37
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
> ```

I couldn't find any information on how to do this and the answer [What is the MySQL datatype SET equivalent in Laravel Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288633/what-is-the-mysql-datatype-set-equivalent-in-laravel-schema) doesn't explain how to insert.

Comment: why you insert 'A' , 'B'. Try with: $table = DB::table('bundles')->insert(['bundle'=>'A']);

Comment: because its a set. A set should be able to hold multiple values. What you are describing is the use case for an Enum.

Comment: @NiteyaShah I believe you have to pass it as a string, not an array: `DB::table('bundles')->insert(['bundle'=> 'A,B'])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the implode function, that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SET` column, your insert method should be :

```
$insert = DB::table('bundles')
       ->insert(['bundle' => 'A,B']);
```